# Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'grid' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, razor, webmatrix

### I'm a NEWBIE in Razor C# / Webmatrix 3.0. I"m getting this error below when I try to compile this code. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!!

Server Error in '/' Application.

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'grid' does not exist in the current context

Source Error:

Line 76:
Line 77: 
Line 78:     @grid.GetHtml(
Line 79:     tableStyle: "grid",
Line 80:     headerStyle: "head",

Source File: c:\Users\user2\Documents\My Web Sites\test\test.cshtml    Line: 78

Compiler Warning Messages:

Show Detailed Compiler Output:

---

```
@{
var db = Database.Open("REST") ;
var searchTerm = "";
var searchRestS = "";
var searchGroupS = "";
var searchYearS = "";
var searchMonthS = "";
var searchDayS = "";
var searchDateS = Request.QueryString["searchDay"] + "/" +  
Request.QueryString["searchMonth"] +  
"/" + Request.QueryString["searchYear"];
IEnumerable<dynamic> selectedData = null;
var message="";

Validation.RequireField("searchRest", "Codigo do restaurante nao foi fornecido");
Validation.RequireField("searchGroup", "Grupo do prato nao foi fornecido");
Validation.Add("searchDate", Validator.DateTime("Data invalida"));


if (IsPost)  {

    if (Validation.IsValid()) 
      {

        searchRestS = "%" + Request.QueryString["searchRest"] + "%";
        searchGroupS = "%" + Request["searchGroup"] + "%";
        searchYearS = "%" + Request["searchYear"] + "%";
        searchMonthS = "%" + Request["searchMonth"] + "%";
        searchDayS = "%" + Request["searchDay"] + "%";
          var selectCommand = "SELECT * FROM CRRP_RESUMO_PRATO WHERE 
              crrp_cod_restaurante = @0  
              AND datepart (YEAR, crrp_dat_movimento) = @4 
              AND datepart (MONTH, crrp_dat_movimento) = @3 
              AND datepart (DAY, crrp_dat_movimento) = @2 
              AND crrp_tip_resumo = 0 AND crrp_cod_grupo = @1";
        selectedData = db.Query(selectCommand, searchRestS, searchGroupS, searchDayS,
        searchMonthS, searchYearS); 
        var grid = new WebGrid(source: selectedData, defaultSort:"Prato", 
        rowsPerPage:13);
      }


          }

}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Pratos Vendidos</title>
    <style type="text/css">
.grid { margin: 4px; border-collapse: collapse; width: 600px; }
.grid th, .grid td { border: 1px solid #C0C0C0; padding: 5px; }
.head { background-color: #E8E8E8; font-weight: bold; color: #FFF; }
.alt { background-color: #E8E8E8; color: #000; }
</style> 
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Pratos Vendidos</h1>
<form method="get">
<div>
<label for="searchRest">Codigo do Restaurante:</label>
<input type="text" name="searchRest" value="@Request.QueryString["searchRest"]" /> 
<br/>    
(N, F, P, A)<br/>
</div>
<div>
<label for="searchGroup">Codigo do Grupo</label>
<input type="text" name="searchGroup" value="@Request.QueryString["searchGroup"]" />
<br/>   
(6, 7, 9, E, F, G, P, S)<br/>
</div>
<div>
<label for="searchDay">Data</label>
<input name="searchDay" type="text" id="searchDay"    
value="@Request.QueryString["searchDay"]" /> 
<input name="searchMonth" type="text" id="searchMonth" 
value="@Request.QueryString["searchMonth"]" />
<input name="searchYear" type="text" id="searchYear"   
value="@Request.QueryString["searchYear"]" />  <br/> 
(DD MM YYYY)<br/>
<input type="Submit" value="Search Description" />
</div>
</form>

<div>
@grid.GetHtml(
tableStyle: "grid",
headerStyle: "head",
alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
columns: grid.Columns(
    grid.Column("Restaurante"),
    grid.Column("Codigo"),
    grid.Column("Prato"),
    grid.Column("DataDaVenda"),
    grid.Column("Quantidade")
                     )
            )

</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to simplify your sample by removing all the irrelevant parts. Nobody is going to read all that.

Comment: It looks like some people did... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Your `grid` variable is declared inside the scope of `if (Validation.IsValid())` and cannot be used anywhere else. If you want to access it outside of if statement, you must declare it before `if (IsPost)`.

Comment: Gday Mozgow, I've made the suggested change but I'm still getting the same error :(

Comment: YES !!
Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'grid' does not exist in the current context

Source Error:


Line 74: </div>
Line 75: <div>
Line 76: @grid.GetHtml(
Line 77:     tableStyle: "grid",
Line 78:     headerStyle: "head",

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, please try placing the following  tag  within the  enclosure.

```
<div>
@grid.GetHtml(
tableStyle: "grid",
headerStyle: "head",
alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
columns: grid.Columns(
    grid.Column("Restaurante"),
    grid.Column("Codigo"),
    grid.Column("Prato"),
    grid.Column("DataDaVenda"),
    grid.Column("Quantidade")
                     )
            )

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, mate ... sorry about my ignorance but what do you mean by "enclosure"??

Comment: Sorry..  No ignorance on your part just really bad language on mine.  Place it within the <form></form> tag..  Sorry about that, not sure why I said enclosure. lol

Comment: No worries, Mikey, I've made the suggested change but I'm still getting the same error :(